# Looking for ways to watch PS Vue on Ubuntu

Tags: streaming, tv

PS Vue does not allow linux users to stream their content over any browsers.  I know some people got Vue to work on Kodi, I am not one of them.  Is there an way to get ROKU (which I know has a windows app), Amazon Fire, or Android TV on ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

as of today ps vue has switched to an html 5 player.  I tested on 18.04b2 and it's working great